# How to use "map.get(key)" in Thymeleaf - Broadleaf Ecom

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf, broadleaf-commerce

I have a `Hashmap (String, List<Offers>)`, passed to a Thymeleaf page. I am getting this map on the page and I can access it.

How can I do `map.get(key)` with Thymeleaf? I just need to fetch the values based on a certain key and then parse and print that value, which I know and have the logic for.

I am running a Broadleaf application and Thymeleaf is the UI engine for it.

Answer (score 37):

Using `${map.get(key)}` (where `key` is a variable) works for me.

`${map['key']}` only seems to work for *String literal* keys -- if the `key` you're looking up is a *variable* then `${map[key]}` *doesn't seem to work*.

#### Accessing Map entries given a list of keys

Here's a full example, looking up items in a HashMap `map` given `listOfKeys` an ordered List of the keys of elements I want to get from the map. Using a separate `listOfKeys` like this lets me control the order of iteration, and optionally return only a subset of elements from the map:

```
<ul>
    <li th:each="key: ${listOfKeys}"">
        <span th:text="${key}"></span> = <span th:text="${map.get(key)}"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

#### Looping through every entry in a Map

If you do not have an ordered list of keys, but just want to loop through *every* item in the Map, then you can loop directly through the map's `keySet()` (But you will have no control of the ordering of keys returned if your map is a `HashMap`):

```
<ul>
    <li th:each="key: ${map.keySet()}">
        <span th:text="${key}"></span> = <span th:text="${map.get(key)}"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This usage can be expressed even more concisely by simply iterating through the `entrySet` of the map, and accessing each returned entry's `key` and `value` members:

```
<ul>
    <li th:each="entry: ${map}">
        <span th:text="${entry.key}"></span> = <span th:text="${entry.value}"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I also observe that `map['key']` always returns a String. Additionally it seems that `map.get('key')` also always returns a String. If my map contains an object, how can I return that type in thymeleaf? (Outside of Java, `map.get('key').getClass()` returns the correct object type).

Answer (score 24):

You can simply use `${map.get('key')}`

Comment: It works with static string, but can you tell me how to do that with a variable?

Comment: I think instead of static key you can pass variable too... `<tr th:each="key : ${list_of_keys}"> <span>${map.get(key)}</span>`

Comment: You can pass variable instead of 'key'.
If you need to get key per key-value pair, use `${hashMapVariable.getKey()`

Answer (score 9):

The way to access the value:

```
${map[__${key}__]}
```

You have to put the key between doubled underscores to make a pre-processing for the key variable.

Comment: I observe that `map.get('key')` and `map['key']` work the same way, at least for String type key values.

Answer (score 8):

I am using with drop down box the following for example to loop keys on maps

```
<select id="testId">
        <option th:each="item: ${itemsMap}" 
                th:value="${item['key']}"
                th:text="${item['value']}" />
</select>
```

in case of getting a specific value, I'm using

```
${itemsMap.get('key')}
```

Comment: This works but it seems to only ever return a String object, regardless of the object stored in the map. Is this expected?

Comment: The key must be an object not primitive type, so it accepts String, Integer, Double. I use it like that in my project, but don't use the quota in those cases.

Answer (score 5):

In my situation, where I had a `HashMap<String, String>`, I had to do the lookup like this

```
<strong th:text="${map['__${entry.key}__']}"></strong>
```

Answer (score 3):

The way to access the map value for a certain key `keyaccess`, assuming you have the map `mymap` in your model:

```
${mymap['keyaccess']}
```

That would give you the list associated to your entry, now you could iterate it.

In case you need, you could iterate a map in the same way you could iterate any other supported iterable objects, from the [documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#iteration-basics):

> Not only java.util.List objects can be used for iteration in
>   Thymeleaf. In fact, there is a quite complete set of objects that are
>   considered iterable by a th:each attribute:
>
> - Any object implementing java.util.Iterable
> - Any object implementing java.util.Map. When iterating maps, iter variables will be of class java.util.Map.Entry.
> - Any array
> - Any other object will be treated as if it were a single-valued list containing the object itself.

Comment: It works with static string, but can you tell me how to do that with a variable?

Comment: @GregoriusEdwadr `${map[__${key}__]}`

Answer (score 1):

remarksMap is TreeMap and "id" is Long type value

```
<div th:if="${#maps.containsKey(remarksMap, id)}">
   <textarea th:text="${remarksMap.get(id)}" rows="2" cols="30" maxlength="250" 
       autocomplete="off"></textarea>                               
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the answers lead me in the right direction.  The following code from (a table column detail) works:

```
<td>[[${statusesMap.get('__${employee.status}__')}]]</td>
```

statusesMap is a Map<String, String>
Employee is an employee class with a field called 'status'.

Note the single quotes. It did not work without them.