# Thymeleaf: How to use ${} in ${}

Tags: thymeleaf

Is there any way to put `${}` in `${}`?

I want to put `${}` as a key value in HashMap.

I tried

```html
<td th:text="${nickNames[${reviewId}]}">
```

Comment: You cannot nest expressions like that. But you don't need to. Have you researched [similar questions and their answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=thymeleaf+hashmap+site%253Astackoverflow.com)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use "map.get(key)" in Thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28621301/how-to-use-map-getkey-in-thymeleaf-broadleaf-ecom)