# Retrieve individual values from Map<Long,String> by key in Thymeleaf without iteration

Tags: java, spring-boot, dictionary, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I tried all the different variations of `myMap.get(key)`, `myMap[key]`, etc. to get this line of code working where `myMap` is a `Map<Long,String>` and `thing` has a property called `state`:

```
<span th:text="${myMap.get(__${thing.state}__)}"></span>
```

Any syntactically valid variation I could come up with would only result in empty text.

The only thing that ultimately worked was using a `Map<Integer,String>` instead. I'm still passing a `long` into `myMap.get()`. Thankfully my value range for the particular use case is within the range of `Integer`.

How do I write this line of code to be able to use a `Map<Long,String>` when I need to?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use "map.get(key)" in Thymeleaf - Broadleaf Ecom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28621301/how-to-use-map-getkey-in-thymeleaf-broadleaf-ecom)

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following:

```
Map<Long, String> foodMap = new HashMap<>();
foodMap.put(1L, "Ham & Eggs");
context.setVariable("food", foodMap);
context.setVariable("keyer", new Keyer(1));
```

With this for my key:

```
static class Keyer {

  public Keyer(long key) {
    this.key = key;
  }

  private long key;

  public long getKey() {
    return key;
  }

  public void setKey(long key) {
    this.key = key;
  }
}
```

And each of these worked:

```
<span th:text="${food[keyer.key]}" />
<span th:text="${food.get(keyer.key)}" />
<span th:text="${food.get(1L)}" />
```

Output:

```
<span >Ham &amp; Eggs</span>
<span >Ham &amp; Eggs</span>
<span >Ham &amp; Eggs</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason your example does not work as expected is a combination of these two facts:

- By coding `__${...}__` you trigger [preprocessing](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#preprocessing) the contained expression. Preprocessing adds back the result of the expression as text to the surrounding expression and is processed again in a second round. Thymeleaf/SPEL does not have a good hint to interpret the result as `java.lang.Long` and hence the next best attempt is to parse it into `java.lang.Integer`.
- `java.lang.Integer` and `java.lang.Long` do not compare (and maps rely on the result of `equals`).

```
Integer i = 42;
Long l = 42L;
System.out.println(l.equals(i)); // the output is 'false'
```

The solution depends on wether you actually need preprocessing and how `thing.state` is declared:

1. If it is a `long` or `java.lang.Long` and there is no good argument for preprocessing it you can simply write:

```
${myMap.get(thing.state)}
```

2. If it has a different type (e.g. String) or you definitely need it to be preprocessed you can explicitly convert it to long by adding an 'L' suffix:

```
${myMap.get(__${thing.state + 'L'}__)}
```

3. Similar to option 2 you could adapt your code to make `thing.state` resolve to a string ending with 'L'.

(tested with Thymeleaf 3.0.15.RELEASE)

Hints:

- Option 1 is expected to be slightly faster.
- Option 2 and 3 only will raise an exception if the resulting expression is not numeric (as the original expression would as well).